# Error when trying to import data from a CSV file into an AWS Postgres DB

Tags: python, database, postgresql, csv, amazon-s3

I am trying to insert a CSV file that is stored in an AWS s3 bucket, into a Postgres database, using the `aws_s3.table_import_from_s3` function in a psql session. It seems it is working (all the `varchar` data in the table seems to be accepted) until it hits a boolean. I am wondering what I could do, to get it to accept my data.

My code looks like this:

```
postgres=> SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3(
   'my_table',
   '', 
   '(format csv)',
   :'s3_uri'
);
```

Then I am met with this error:

> ```
> invalid input syntax for type boolean: "Mixed Breed"
> CONTEXT:  COPY my_table, line 1, column mixed_breed: "Mixed Breed"
> ```

The CSV data was pulled from an API, and created in Python. I double checked using types that it is boolean data type. The values are all "True" and "False" in the column.

Any suggestions for a fix? ChatGPT is not helping.

Comment: ChatGPT can only help once it has stolen and anonymized existing answers from the interwebs. Probably a rare problem.

Answer (score 0):

The [`aws_s3.table_import_from_s3`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PostgreSQL.S3Import.html#aws_s3.table_import_from_s3) function hides a `COPY` command inside. And the error msg. indicates column headers. So try adding [`header`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html#id-1.9.3.55.6):

```
SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3('my_table', '', '(format csv, header)', :'s3_uri');
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html#id-1.9.3.55.6)

> On input, the first line is discarded when this option is set to true

The only other explanation would invalid data in the source. But you ruled that out:

> I double checked using types that it is boolean data type. The values are all "True" and "False" in the column.